# ASP.NET Core 3 disable reload on change appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using default host builder to start ASP.NET Core 3 kestrel server.

```cs
CreateHostBuilder(args)
    .Build()
    .Run();
```

Now I want to disable reloading when "appsettings.json" changes. Because my CI/CD job removes files from server then uploads new files. During that time If the server needs to connect database I get connection string missing error due to "appsettings.json" file removed. That's why I want to disable reload on change.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2939) on GitHub, but it doesn't describes how to disable `reloadOnChange`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like starting .NET 6.x there's a new flag [introduced](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/pull/2940/files) for disabling automatic config reloads using `hostbuilder:reloadConfigOnChange` config value.

However, I would suggest creating custom builder and configuring application config paths alongside with reload arguments for custom needs.